# Why isn't tensorflow installing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cmd, pip

I can't install tensorflow! Showing this error!

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

[image]

I installed Python 3.11, but I got the same error message again. I googled the error and tried some of the things which were suggested to other people, but nothing worked (this included installing Flask).

How can I install Tensorflow? Thanks.

Comment: requirements are Python 3.7–3.10

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 6):

Currently, Tensorflow is not yet supported for your python version which is "3.11". Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#:%7E:text=TensorFlow%20is%20tested%20and%20supported,or%20later%20(with%20C%2B%2B%20redistributable)) for the supported systems and versions.

My recommendation is to use a virtual environment or a conda environment and install a supported version of python for the corresponding TensorFlow version.

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to see how to create a virtual environment.

Check this [guide](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) on how to set up a conda environment.